# Move mysql.sock outside from /tmp folder (WHM/cPanel)

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, cpanel, whm

I currently have problem with mysql.sock file that automatically get created in /tmp folder and it keep filling up the tmp folder. I've been trying to move it out from /tmp folder to /home/tmp by create a new link using this command

```
ln -sv /var/lib/mysql/mysq.sock /home/tmp/mysql.sock
```

and add these lines to my.cnf

```
[client]
socket = /home/tmp/mysql.sock
[mysql]
socket = /home/tmp/mysql.sock
[mysqld]
socket = /home/tmp/mysql.sock
```

as well as changing socket path in PHP.ini. Everytime I restarted the mysql it still keep creating in /tmp folder and doesn't even use the one I created in /home/tmp (I check by renaming /tmp/mysql.sock to something while it's running)

Note: I'm checking variables through PHPMyAdmin and for socket it showing /home/tmp/mysql.sock

Comment: that doesn't "move" the socket. you're just creating a symlink pointing at the original socket file. that's like saying "we're moving to 123 main street", then putting a note on 123's front door saying "we're really still in the original location". mysql is likely to IGNORE a symlink anyways, because that symlink is NOT under its control and can be used to point at ANY file on the system. which meansmysql would try to overwrite/replace that other file.

Comment: The symlink is backwards anyways.  The target file should be first, link second.

Comment: Do you have any ideas where mysql get the path to create the socket file? Which in this case is /tmp

Comment: @IttikornS. this really has nothing to do with programming so is pretty off-topic for stackoverflow.   Even with it being a system administration issue, it seems like a non-issue to me.  I've never heard of a socket using up lots of disk space.

Comment: a socket file consumes an inode, and at most a couple kbytes of actual disk space. mysql would simply re-use any existing socket file when it starts up anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a symlink.  Remove it.

Change the socket value in my.cnf:

```
socket   = /home/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Restart MySQLd.

You shouldn't have to change php.ini:

```
 ; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
 ; MySQL defaults.
```

As long as php.ini isn't instructed otherwise, it will just get the socket location from MySQL itself.

You *should* make sure that the MySQL user has *permission* to create the socket in /home/tmp/ ... if it doesn't, it would default back to the original /tmp location.